# PHP/HTML help, not logging in

Tags: php, html, database, authentication

The database is set up correctly but I the error handler when I dont enter a username or password is not working. I always get Invalid username and/or password
The following code doesn't go the the "loginhandler.php" link
Any ideas to why?
No matter the input the code executes`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php

$okay = FALSE;
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$onError = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    $onError = 'Please Enter your Username';
    $okay = FALSE;
}

if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $onError = 'Please Enter your password';
    $okay = FALSE;
}
    if($okay == FALSE)
    {
    $dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db('db_name', $dbc);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password='" .         $password . "'";
    if ($result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)) {// Run the query.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $okay = true;
        }
    } else {

    }
}
if ($okay) {
    //  session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Loction: loginhandler.php');
    exit() ;
} else {
    $onError = "Invalid username and/or password";
}
}
?>
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div id="container">
    <form id='login' action='login.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $onError; ?></div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <div id="lower">
            <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
            <p><a href="signup.html">Click here to Signup.</a></p>;
        </div><!--/ lower-->
    </form>
</div><!--/ container-->
<!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
</html>`
    $onError = "Invalid username and/or password";
```

Comment: `if($okay == FALSE)` to `if($okay == TRUE)`

Comment: This line has a typo: header('Loction: loginhandler.php'); Should be header('Location: loginhandler.php');

Comment: CHanged to ('Location: loginhandler.php') still no difference

Comment: There's also a stray line of PHP outside of <?php tags at the very end: $onError = "Invalid username and/or password";

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a copy/paste error, but at the end of your code, after the closing html tag, there is a php variable declaration. Not sure what it's doing, just hanging out there. It won't execute unless it's between <?php ?> tags. Looks like it shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score -1):

First, you are using session. add `session_start()` at the top of the page.

`header('Location: loginhandler.php');` you wrote Location wrong.

`if($okay == FALSE)` Should be `if($okay == TRUE)`

And you alweyes getting the invalid message because you have `"$onError = "Invalid username and/or password";"` at the bottom of the code outside any PHP tags.

Comment: Did all this, now no message but page just reload login.php

Comment: $onError = "Invalid username and/or password"; here you are not showing anything. add `echo $onError;` so you could see if there is an error with the username/password.